# iBooks ERROR ITMS-9000 - problem with id

Tags: epub, apple-books

I tried submitting my first epub to iBooks and got this error:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "Shankle.epub: OEBPS/Text/introduction.xhtml(11): value of attribute "id" is invalid; must be an XML name without colons
```

Here's the code from introduction.xhtml, line 11:

```
<p class="pfirst"><span class="PageNumber" id="13">Page 13</span> It is the purpose of this book to record the facts about the various state names. nicknames, flowers, trees, flags, birds, songs, seals, mottoes, capitol buildings, and some of the outstanding state histories.</p>
```

I'm confused; there are no colons in my code. It's just `id="13"`. My epub shows no errors in Epub-Checker. Does anyone know what this error means?

Comment: Please note that there are formatting tools on the top bar of the editing window that let you write down raw code without being processed, so it will be displayed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An XML name must begin with a letter, underscore or colon (although in this case, the colon is prohibited).

See https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006.html#sec-common-syn

Comment: Now I get it - I think. id="13" doesn't work because it begins with a numeral. So all I have to do is add a letter or an underscore - id="a13" or id="_13". I'll give that a try. It's weird that neither Sigil nor Epub-Checker caught that.